# Facebook SDK UiLifeCycleHelper on Android "on

Tags: android, facebook

I have 3 pages right now. I am also using the most recent Facebook SDK.

```
Landing Page -> Sign in/Login Page -> MainActivity
```

At the moment, I'm trying to implement logging in where that goes from the `Landing Page` to options of signing/logging in and if logged in or signed in on Facebook with permissions, I am directed to `MainActivity`. I want it so that if my `MainActivity` is `destroyed()`, using `UiLifeCycleHelper` it should redirect me back to `MainActivity` rather than starting over in the landing page.

So a couple of questions:
1. How can I implement this? 
2. Will I need to create a `UiLifeCycleHelper` on each activity?
3. Will I need to use this code on each activity? (i.e. `MainActivity, Landing Page and Sign in`)

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session == null) {
                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    session = Session.restoreSession(activity, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
                }
                if (session == null) {
                    session = new Session(activity);
                }
                Session.setActiveSession(session);
            }
```

If so, which activity do I put in `restoreSession(activity, null, statusCallback, savedinstanceState)`, the activity I'm in or the activity I'm trying to restore? (i.e. I'm trying to restore `MainActivity`, should I put that in if I have that code in my landing page?)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? i'm in the same situation... maybe some code example of what you did there would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an answer which is base on the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/#step1) on the Facebook Developers page, the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119251/android-existing-fragment-conflicting-with-facebook-sdk/22121378?noredirect=1#comment33586363_22121378).

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond but I'm using 3 different activities, just wondering if I can somehow use the uilifecyclehelper instead